# How to make a change value of a variable to call a function?

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I'm trying to make a function to be called when the value of a particular variable is changed. I thought about using it to bind but I can't make it work. Here is the relevant code snippets:

```
def runSim (self):

    if self.openned.get() ==  1:
        self.p = multiprocessing.Process(target= self.runProg).start()

    elif self.openned.get() ==  0:
        saveFirst = tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Warning",
                                             "This is a new file. For run this, please save first")
        if saveFirst:
            self.saveAs()
            self.openned.set(1)
            self.p = multiprocessing.Process(target= self.runProg).start()

def runProg(self):
    """This funcion will run the simulation"""

    a = open(self.nameFile.get(),"w")
    self.writeFile()

    self.process = subprocess.Popen([self.cmdSys.get()+self.dV.get()+
                                     self.extension.get(),self.nameFile.get()])
    self.pid.set(self.process.pid)
    if self.process.wait() is 0:
        #here is the part where the function have to be called when the variable's values is changed!!!

def callMsg(self):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("","Your simulation was completed sucessfully.")
```

How can I use BIND to do this?

Comment: "when the value of a particular variable is changed".  What variable are you talking about specifically?

Comment: As a side note: Checking that anything `is 0` instead of `== 0` is a very bad idea. Python is allowed to create as many integer objects with the value `0` as it wants to, and all you ever care about is whether you've got a `0`, not whether you've got the same object as the literal.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to trigger when a Tk variable gets changed, you can do that with the [`trace`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) method:

```
self.textvar = Tk.StringVar()
def textvar_callback(self, *args):
    print('My textvar changed!')
self.textvar.trace('w', self.textvar_callback)
```

---

If you're looking to trigger when a regular instance attribute gets changed, you can do that with [`@property`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
@property
def attr(self):
    return self._attr
@attr.setter
def attr(self, value):
    self._attr = attr
    print('My attr changed!')
```

---

If you're looking to trigger when an arbitrary variable gets rebound… you basically can't do that. You will need to replace the code that does that assignment with code that hits your trigger explicitly along with the assignment.

---

And based on the comment in the code, you're not trying to trigger off a variable at all, but rather off the result of a function call. You cannot do that. A function call returns a value which does not later change. The only way to get a new value is to call the function again. You need to work out where to fit the function call into your event loop (or, if that's not possible, spawn a background thread that calls the function repeatedly in a blocking way, and sends a signal to the main thread somehow).